# Display special characters in mx:AdvancedDataGrid flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, advanceddatagrid

I am trying to display special characters in a column of **mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn** as value. For example, i am trying to display copy right symbol, trademark and other characters with HTML code.

I want to display below data

**Special Characters:** ¢ ©® ™

with below html encoded content:

&lt;b&gt;Special Characters:&lt;/b&gt; &cent; &copy;&reg; &trade;

As of now  **mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn** displays the data as is. That is displays the tags (HTML encoded string as is)

sample code:
< mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="htmlContent" >

Here HTML can be anything. Please adivse how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I setted Delta symbol to column header of DataGrid like this

```
<s:DataGrid width="100%" height="100%" rowHeight="43"
            sortableColumns="false"
            color="0x929698"
            borderVisible="false"
            dataProvider="{model.gridOperationDataCollection}">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn> headerRenderer="ru.prognoz.iup.renderers.OperationIndGridHRDelta"/>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
```

OperationIndGridHRDelta

```
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                minWidth="21" minHeight="21">

<mx:Text htmlText="\u0394 {label}"
         color="0xA2ACB2"
         verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0"
         fontSize="12" fontFamily="Arial"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, when you specify the dataField property, Flex will try to set the "text" property of the default AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer (which is a TextField). In order to display html, you need to create a custom item renderer extending AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer, and overriding the "set data" function, then set the htmlText property instead.

Also see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText, some HTML entities are not supported.